# ¿Cómo mostrar mensaje de progreso mientras el botón esta en ejecución?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo una aplicación web en .aspx y con código atras en C#. Tengo un botón de descarga que se demora aproximadamente 2 minutos en ejecutar (tiempo normal de ejecución para lo que estoy haciendo).

Me gustaría agregar un mensaje de espera mientras esto esta en ejecución, y termine cuando el evento del botón ha terminado su ejecución. ¿Como puedo lograr esto?

Incorpore el siguiente codigo en mi la pagina .aspx que me muestra bien el proceso que se esta llevando a cabo.

El problema es que una vez que finaliza, el archivo ya no se descarga, y la ejecucion se termina. En donde estara fallado?

Aqui esta el codigo que implemente:

```
   <div>    
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers> 
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>  
    <center><asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Download"    OnTextChanged="Download" Height="60" Width="160" Font-Size="16" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#C6D5E2" BorderStyle="Groove" OnClick="Download"/></center>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
<ProgressTemplate>
<center><img src="img\loading.gif" />
Download in Progress……..</center>
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
</div>
```

Comment: cuando dices "descarga" es porque realiza el download de un archivo ? No evaluaste lanzar la descarga en una ventana separada ?

Comment: Hola, si perdon por no haber especificado. el boton realiza un download de un archivo, y el proceso completo lo hace el boton desde el codigo behind de C#. cuando se esta descargando, el navegador muestra el proceso en la parte de arriba pero quisiera ser mas evidente y mostrar al usuario que el proceso se esta efectuando y que el mensage se desaparesca una vez la accion esta terminada

Comment: cuando dices: _tiempo normal de ejecución para lo que estoy haciendo_ quiere decir que estas preparando el download ? (por ejemplo con una consulta a la base de datos)  y otra pregunta: estas enviando algun formato especifco ? (por ejemplo: es una imagen, un CSV, etc)

Comment: hola si estoy enviando un archivo csv, que provieve de un meta data de servicios web.

Answer (score 2):

El problema con la descarga es que el Response debe contener el archivo para mostrar el dialogo, con lo cual usar el UpdatePanel con el [UpdateProgress](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-do-i-use-the-aspnet-ajax-updateprogress-control) estaría descartado, no se puede usar esta tecnica para descargar archivos.

El único camino que se me ocurre es descargar el archivo mediante ajax usando

[jquery.fileDownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload)

[jQuery File Download Plugin for Ajax like, feature rich file downloads](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/)

Como veras en el ejemplo del artículo se expone el evento `successCallback` que podrias usar para ocultar el dialogo de descarga que le mostrarías al usuario.

De esta forma con una descarga controlada desde codigo cliente puede iniciar la descarga y ocultarla cuando termine.

Podrias usar el [$.BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#overview) para que el usuario espere la descarga, aunque seguro hay mas opciones.

Comment: hola, gracias por las sugerencias, una pregunta. tendrias algun ejemplo de como implementar lo que me mencionas arriba en tu respuesta? gracias nuevamente

Comment: la verdad no tengo un ejemplo que implemente este caso que planteas, pero si pude ver que en los link que he puesto esta bien explicado como usar la libreria

Comment: Entiendo, trataré de buscar alguno y leer bien la explicación. Una ultima cosa edite pregunta agregando un código que trate de poner pero usando eso el código no me descarga el archivo .csv que antes si se descargaba. Creo que el problema está en que estoy usnado asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger. Tienes alguna sugerencia? gracias nuevamente

Comment: Exacto, el problema es el UpdatePanel, es lo que comente al principio de mi respuesta. El UpdatePanel si bien no actualiza toda la pagina si realiza un postback al evento en el servidor de la seccion marcada como template. Por eso no se puede cambiar el Response enviando un archivo. La alternativa que veo es hacerlo por ajax (en donde el response no interviene) con la ayuda de una libreria de jquery.

Comment: @Aarancibia si tienes dudas como utilizar $.BlockUI puedes crear una pregunta nueva así te podemos ayudar con ese caso en particular.